# PHP JSON Encode square bracket

Tags: php, json, encode, square-bracket

I have a simple JSON array I am trying to encode. Inside of the JSON string I need another array in square brackets. I am unable to figure out how to make the internal brackets square. Any advice?

Here is my code

```
$data = [ "item" =>  ["id" => "123456", "name" => "adam"]  ];                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

Here is the output

```
{"item":{"id":"123456","name":"adam"}}
```

What I am hoping to get

```
{"item":["1123","1134","1184"]}
```

Comment: How can you give it something with one number and get something with many numbers back? (The implication here is that we need a more complete example).

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. This question is Unclear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In JSON `[]` is an array and `{}` is an object.

An array holds an ordered list of values.

An object holds an unordered group of key / value pairs.

If you want an array, then you have to provide an ordered list of values (a PHP array) and not a set of key / value pairs (a PHP associative array).

---

```
$data = [ "item" =>  ["id", "123456", "name", "adam"]  ];
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

gives

```
{"item":["id","123456","name","adam"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, JSON array can not have keys and values at the same time, as for javascript. If you have php array with keys and values, that will be converted to Object for JSON, remove keys from php array and you will get JSON array too.